# Implementing class inheritance in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, inheritance

I am confused, again, about implementing OOP in CodeIgniter.

By design, I have two classes, namely Customer and Supplier. Both classes extends a super class I call Institution.

It was not a problem for me when I wrote them using only php (without framework).

```
class Customer extends Institution {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

class Supplier extends Institution {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

class Institution extends DBConnection {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

class DBConnection {
    // do CRUD activities here
}
```

The questions are:

1. How do I write them using CI?
2. Is it as Controller or in Model the best way to implement them? What factors should be considered?

A friend suggested a way I thought a bit hacky, model extends model. I try, if possible, to do it in codeigniter-appropriate way.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as it is going to be your domain model entities, it should be models. And there is nothing wrong in having another `model` class as a base class for `model` class. So, you'll just need to make your `Institution` (or `DBConnection` if you prefer to keep it)  class extend `CI_Model`.

Comment: forgot to comeback after reading your answer. it makes more sense to me with them as models rather than controller. so i took your suggestion and constructed them all as ones.